# How can I access the text response of a fetch from client JS to fastify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, fastify

I have a fastify node.js app that I am able to see the text results of a promise right before it is returned to the calling browser JS.  When that promise is returned to the browser JS, I only get am empty string out of the promise text.  I am assuming that the promises are not chained and this is a new promise that does not have the contents of the other.  If that is correct, how would I access the inner promise results?

I have passed promises between modules in the fastify app with no problem getting the results at any point, I just do not understand what I am doing wrong at this point.  These are the basics of what I am trying to do on both sides of the call:

```
// node.js
fastify.get('/promise', async function(request, reply) {
    var results = await someFunction(request)
    console.log(await results.text()) // this displays results as XML
    return results
})

// call to fastify app from browser JS
async function getPromise(params) {
    var response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/promise" + params, { mode: 'no-cors' })
    console.log(await response.text()) // this is empty
}
```

Comment: you should return `results.text()` not only `results`

Comment: I tried returning both `return { results, text }` where both vars are saved with an `await` beforehand.  On the client side, both values are undefined, when I do that.  Do the promises not chain?  My understanding was that passing the promise down the line worked, but maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: you are correct, it seems odd that `const text = await results.text()` doesn't work
are you sure there are not any errors? like cors or others?

Comment: There are no errors seen in either the browser or fastify logging I have up.  I have that exact line for the text that I passed in.  I'm assuming `let { results, text } = await fetch...` should work fine on the calling side?  It's passed with no errors, but outputting `results` and `text` on the client call is undefined.  The node outputs the correct information before returning.

Comment: Could you check in your client [`response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) ?

Comment: Last question, then I think I found, the client is on the same base url of the apis?

Comment: So `response.ok` on the client side response is actually `false` while it's `true` on the server side, before the return.  Second question: I'm running it on a development environment, so they are both on localhost, yes.

Comment: added response, it was the mode the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{ mode: 'no-cors' }` [is blocking you to access](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) the response because it is [opaque](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode)

> An opaque filtered response is a filtered response whose type is "opaque", URL list is the empty list, status is 0, status message is the empty byte sequence, header list is empty, and body is null.

Here a complete example:

```
'use strict'

const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const fastifyCors = require('fastify-cors')

fastify.register(fastifyCors, {
  credentials: true,
  origin: '*'
})

fastify.get('/promise', async function (request, reply) {
  const results = await fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e738e46300000fd9b2e66ae')
  return results.text()
})

fastify.listen(3000)
```

In the browser:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/promise").then(res => res.text())
```

It will print `HELLO WORLD`

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly the issue! Thank you!